# Double JSF only without comma or dot

Tags: jsf

how is it possible to display a double like *"1"*

At the moment the double appears with *1.0*
But I want to have for example `1,5,` too.

But if I have only `1` (`the numbers after the comma or dot is zero, than I want to have a value without comma or dot`)

How can I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is what you want to achieve:

```
<h:outputText value="1,0">
<f:convertNumber minFractionDigits="0" />
</h:outputText>
```

Will output 1

```
<h:outputText value="1,5">
<f:convertNumber minFractionDigits="0" />
</h:outputText>
```

Will output 1,5

Make sure to use correct decimal separator depending on your Locale when testing this.

You can play arround a bit more with the f:convertNumber tag. http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/core/f_convertNumber.html